# Python: matching a word in dictionary value

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

Is there a way to search a dictionary value to match a specific word in python 2.7. I tried making use of the any() command, but this doesn't return anything useful, am I on the right track?

```
dict = {'1' : 'see john run'}
test = 'run'

if any (x in test for x in Dict.values()):
    print "true"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the right idea, but you need to switch the arguments in the `in` test

```
data = {'1' : 'see john run'}
test = 'run'

if any(test in x for x in data.values()):
    print "true"
```

Comment: You can just `print any(test in x for x in data.values())`

Answer (score 1):

Just try the following:

```
print test in mydict.values()[0].split()
```

---

```
>>> mydict = {'1' : 'see john run'}
>>> test = 'run'
>>> print test in mydict.values()[0].split()
True
>>>
```

Also, i'd suggest changing the variable name `dict` to something else (I used `mydict`) because `dict` shadows the built-in.